# non-oscillatory behavior of modified Bessel equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to prove the Bessel modified equation $$x^2y''+xy'-(x^2+n^2)y=0$$
> has no oscillatory solution (preferably using comparison theorem)?

For $x>0$ we have one zero of any solution of $$x^2y''+xy'-n^2y=0$$ lies between any two consecutive zeroes of solutions of the former one. But the latter equation has solutions of the form $\displaystyle y=Ax^n+\frac{B}{x^n}$, which has at most one positive zero $\bigg($say for example, $\displaystyle y=x-\frac1x\bigg)$. So we can expect at least two positive zeroes of the given equation, which contradicts the non-oscillatory behavior.

What is possibly wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean function to be oscilatory?

Comment: Functions having more than one zero, for example : $\sin x,\cos x,J_n(x)$ etc.

Comment: There is a flaw in your reasoning: Sturm comparison theorem says that between any two zeros of a nontrivial solution of the first ODE there is at least one zero of every nontrivial solution of the second ODE. However, this does not imply that every zero of a nontrivial solution of the second ODE is between two zeros of a nontrivial solution of  the first ODE.

Answer (score 1):

The Euler-Cauchy terms determine the behavior for $x\approx 0$. The long-term behavior is determined by the terms with the largest coefficients for $x\to\infty$, thus here
$$
y''(x)-y(x)=0,
$$
which has exponential solutions (with real exponential factors). Combinations of $e^{\pm x}$ do not oscillate.